# incorporating how many times the DVDs have been checked out by customers across all libraries in my sql statement

Tags: oracle

I need to write a query that display all DVD title, length, release_date, and how many times it has been checked out by all customers across all libraries. I need to include the DVDs that have not been checked out in my query results.

Here is my query:

```
`select distinct ci.title, ci.RELEASE_DATE, d.length from catalog_item 
ci  join dvd d on ci.catalog_item_id=d.catalog_item_id
left join physical_item pi on ci.CATALOG_ITEM_ID=pi.CATALOG_ITEM_ID
left join branch b on pi.BRANCH_ID=pi.BRANCH_ID
left join library l on b.LIBRARY_ID=l.LIBRARY_ID
order by ci.TITLE;`
```

my current output is as follows:

```
`Title  Release Date    Length
Inception   8-Jul-10    2:28
La La Land  9-Dec-16    2:08
Moonrise Kingdom    25-May-12   1:34
The Secret Life of the Brain    1-Oct-10    2:00
The Social Network  1-Oct-10    2:01`
```

I have a diagram that I don't know how to share. But it is unclear where to upload it.

Comment: For how to upload your diagram check this post: [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
 SELECT count(*) check_outs,  ci.title, ci.release_date, d.LENGTH
    FROM catalog_item ci
         JOIN dvd d ON ci.catalog_item_id = d.catalog_item_id
         LEFT JOIN physical_item pi ON ci.catalog_item_id = pi.catalog_item_id
         LEFT JOIN branch b ON pi.branch_id = pi.branch_id
         LEFT JOIN library l ON b.library_id = l.library_id
         group by  ci.title, ci.release_date, d.LENGTH
ORDER BY ci.title;
```